# Fingerprint not working in 18.10

Tags: 18.10

I've dell 3648. I upgraded from 18.4.1 to 18.10 and the fingerprint doesn't work at all though I'm successfully able to register my fingerprints but not able to use it to log in. I'm still using my password.

Answer (score 1):

After registering, you have to run:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

and tick the option "Fingerprint authentication".

It seems to be an Ubuntu bug that this is not activated automatically.